# aws codedeploy - .git directory is not found

Tags: git, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy this code (https://github.com/ashwinikumar251/spring-petclinic/) via aws codedeploy and getting below error

[stdout][ERROR] Failed to execute goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.2:revision (default) on project spring-petclinic: .git directory is not found! Please specify a valid [dotGitDirectory] in your pom.xml

I checked manually into ec2 instance and found there is no .git directory .

i tried installing code manually with git clone :

```
git clone https://github.com/ashwinikumar251/spring-petclinic.git
cd spring-petclinic
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

This attempt was successful with .git directory inside the spring-petclinic .

I am not able to find what is preventing .git directory to be created when deploying via codedeploy .

Comment: I suppose that ```.git``` folder is not available in Codedeploy by default, unfortunately. Because I have same problem

Answer (score -1):

Can you send me a screenshot of where you have entered the git repo in the console before deploying a revision?

I think you're not typing in the correct path. The repo name should be ashwinikumar251/spring-petclinic that too after you authenticate github on AWS console. Can you try that and tell me?